# Global variable not surviving across classes?

Tags: vba, excel

I have one UserForm `mailForm`, a custom class `Document` and a module `utilities` which is declared as `Option Private Module`.

The following sequence might raise an error:

- The user clicks a button on the form to call `mailForm`'s method `Public Sub sendEmail()`
- This method calls itself the `Document`'s method `Public Sub generatePDF()`
- This method calls itself the `utilities`'s macro `Public Sub printPDF()`

To sum up, the sequence is: `user` --> `sendEmail() :: form` --> `generatePDF() :: class` --> `printPDF() :: utilities`.

In the macro `printPDF()` of the module `utilities`, I might have an error raised during PDF's generation. The trigger of this error should stop the execution of the user's action to send the email.

Hence, I have declared the global variable (`Dim errorWhilePDF As Boolean`) and put the declaration on top of the class module.
If the error occurs in the macro `printPDF()`, I just set `errorWhilePDF = True`.

My issue is that the value `True` of this variable set in the module `utilities` is not kept in the user form, which still reads it as false. If I declare the variable in the `utilities` module, instead, the user form sees it as `Empty`.

How should I declare my variable `errorWhilePDF` in order to have it set in the module `utilities` and used in the user form, knowing that I'm passing through the class `Document`?

Comment: Look at using events from the class to control it.

Comment: @SMeaden I've tried to declare it as Global on top of the module and it worked, thanks! If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it.

Comment: As for the return value, the function is already returning a string with the file path. I might return a string with an error code, but I found cleaner to have a variable for that.

Comment: Have your subroutines return a boolean to indicate if they succeeded or not. No need to have a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for truly global use Global keyword on a variable defined in a standard module not a class module. Class modules are per instance (with an exception [Static class in VBA](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/02/static-classes-in-excel-vba.html)).